# How fast will my items sell out?

Tags: ios, tiny-tower

Is there a formula to how fast something will sell out??

It would be nice to somehow stack most items to sell out at the same time or create some pattern for max income.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Tiny Tower Wiki](http://tinytowerwiki.com/Strategy/Stock#Sales_Per_Minute) explains that each store has it's own demand (assuming demand is at 100% for that floor category), so sales at any given store are at a constant rate of **10 customers per minute**.

Bitizen buy items randomly, so they'll buy a mix of all items and all items' stock will decrease at the same rate regardless of price. Naturally items with shorter stock will sell out faster.

Due to how sales per minute is handled, you can also "watch" your tower's stock by watching Sales Per Minute; SPM actually calculates *money* earned per minute, so if your SPM is high, that means bitizens are buying more high priced items. This actually means that your low cost items are out of stock, and thus your bitizens can *only* purchase higher cost items.

From the Wiki, about Sales Per Minute:

> Assuming 100% demand (10 bitizens / minute), a single business contributes to this number ...
>   30 if only 3-coin items are stocked
>   25 if 2 and 3-coin items are stocked
>   18 if 1, 2 and 3-coin items are stocked

The wiki also has an advanced [Selective Stocking method](http://tinytowerwiki.com/Strategy/Stock#Advanced_Strategy:_Selective_Stocking) you could use:

> The natural rate of income of each floor is determined by which products are in stock. It follows that a fully employed and stocked floor will reap more coins than one with a single employee and product. However, If the player is able and willing to pay a bit more attention to his or her game, it's very possible to gain even higher rates of income.

Their method shows stocking only 2 and 3 coin items is most profitable because it yields a very high Coins Per Customer rate but doesn't close down the store as often as stocking only 3 coin items would. Note that this only works out if you're actively playing at all times, any time where the game will be left alone you should just fully stock the stores.